# How can i get a live view of syslog-ng logs in a webfrontend?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, websocket, syslog, syslog-ng

I currently have Syslog-ng set up to aggregate my logs. I want to show these logs in real time to my web frontend users. I however have no clue how to do this, is it possible to connect directly to Syslog-ng using WebSockets? Or do I need to first pass it on to something like elasticsearch, if so, how do I get my data live from elasticsearch?

I found [this](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.26/administration-guide/30#TOPIC-1431013) table in the Syslog-ng documentation, but iIcould not find any output destination that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately currently there's no mechanism to export real-time log traffic for a generic destination. You could however write your configuration in a way that places log information for a frontend to read.

For instance, if you have a log statement delivering messages to elastic:

```
log {
  source(s_network);
  destination(d_elastic);
};
```

you could add an alternative destination to the same log statement, which would only serve as a buffer for exporting real-time log data. For instance:

```
log {
  source(s_network);
  destination(d_elastic);
  destination { file("/var/log/buffers/elastic_snapshot.$SEC" overwrite-if-older(59)); };
};
```

Notice the 2nd destination in the log statement above, with curly braces you tell syslog-ng to use an in-line destination instead of a predefined one (or you could use a full-blown destination declaration, but I omitted that for brevity).

This new file destination would write all messages that elastic receives to a file. The file contains the time based macro $SEC, meaning that you'd get a series of files: one for each second in a minute.

Your frontend could just try to find the file with the latest timestamp and present that as the real-time traffic (from the last second).

The overwrite-if-older() option tells syslog-ng that if the file is older than 59 seconds, then it should overwrite it instead of appending to it.

This is a bit hacky, I even intend do implement something what you have asked for in a generic way, but it's doable even today, as long as the syslog-ng configuration is in your control.